# Allow users to update the Manager field on their user record

Tags: user-record

On the user record there is a field called "Manager". It is a standard user object field. I would like to give my users the permission to edit this field themselves, however in the field level security settings on the profile I cannot find this field.
Is it possible to allow users somehow to edit it?
Tia, Lily

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to open up this field for Users. Only user with `Manage Users` and `Manage Internal Users` permission are allowed to update the field.

You can apply a workaround but that will require either APEX code or Flow Process Builder. A nice example of the latter can be found here:

http://www.simplysfdc.com/2015/05/salesforce-update-user-manager.html